# CRTP and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a standard use of the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), for some expression template mechanism, which keeps its children by value:

```
template <typename T, typename>
struct Expr {};

template <typename T>
struct Cst : Expr<T, Cst<T>> 
{
    Cst(T value) : value(std::move(value)) {}

private:
    T value;
};

template <typename T, typename L, typename R>
struct Add : Expr<T, Add<T, L, R>> 
{
    Add(L l, R r) : l(std::move(l)), r(std::move(r))

private:
    L l; R r;
};
```

etc.

Now, when implementing the operator, we **must** pass by reference, since the argument is to be downcast to the right type. The problem is that I find myself implementing four (!) versions of `operator+`:

```
template <typename T, typename L, typename R>
Add<T, L, R> operator+(Expr<T, L>&& l, Expr<T, R>&& r)
{
    return Add<T, L, R>(
        std::move(static_cast<L&>(l)),
        std::move(static_cast<R&>(r)));
}

template <typename T, typename L, typename R>
Add<T, L, R> operator+(const Expr<T, L>& l, Expr<T, R>&& r)
{
    return Add<T, L, R>(
        static_cast<const L&>(l),
        std::move(static_cast<R&>(r)));
}

template <typename T, typename L, typename R>
Add<T, L, R> operator+(Expr<T, L>&& l, const Expr<T, R>& r)
{
    return Add<T, L, R>(
        std::move(static_cast<L&>(l)),
        static_cast<const R&>(r));
}

template <typename T, typename L, typename R>
Add<T, L, R> operator+(const Expr<T, L>& l, const Expr<T, R>& r)
{
    return Add<T, L, R>(
        static_cast<const L&>(l),
        static_cast<const R&>(r));
}
```

Indeed, if the goal is to minimize needless copying, one has to distinguish between temporaries (that can be moved) and lvalues (which must be copied), hence the four overloads.

In C++03, there is "no problem": we use const references and copy all the time, period. In C++11, we can do better, and it is the goal here.

Is there some trick that would allow me to write the addition logic once, or is writing a macro my best option here (since the logic will be repeated for other operators) ?

I'm also open to other suggestions about how to write expression templates with C++11. Just consider that the goal is to minimize copying, since the values stored in terminal nodes may be huge numbers, or matrices (in my precise case, terminal nodes may contain several megabytes of interpolated data, and copy is disabled for these objects -- for other objects, copying is possible).

Comment: Have you tried just passing by value and letting the compiler optimize away the copies?

Comment: Are your objects generally cheap to move? Your constructor somewhat implies that (otherwise you are possibly doing unnecessarie copies by passing by value). In that case you can pass the arguments to `+` by value also (and move them for the constructor call).

Comment: @VaughnCato: It is not possible to pass by value, since the objects would be sliced ! The actual type of `Expr<T, U>` is `U` (`U` always inherits `Expr<T, U>`): this is the whole point of the CRTP. @Grizzly: the objects are cheap to move, expensive to copy.

Comment: Good Point.  I'm not sure of a good solution with it implemented that way, but I have implemented expression templates not using the CRTP before so that the arguments are able to be passed by value.  I could post an answer showing the technique if you are interested.

Comment: "AlexandreC. "It is not possible to pass by value, since the objects would be sliced!" How is it possible that copying an object would slice it, but moving will not?

Comment: @yurikilochek: One must pass by reference in `operator+` to be able to downcast to the right type. The copying or moving is done after the cast.

Comment: I personally use something like `template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs> expression<operators::plus, Lhs, Rhs> operator+(Lhs&&, Rhs&&);`, which has the benefit that no expression wrapper (here, the `expression` type) is constructed if one of the operand is not an expression. `operators::plus` being a run off the mill polymorphic functor. (`operator+` is found by ADL, as usual, but is still actually constrained by SFINAE that at least one of its operand is an expression wrapper.)

Comment: @LucDanton: I use template template parameters too (here it was just to point out the problem with `T` inheriting `expr<T>`, which is very elegantly solved by having it the other way around: `expr<T>` inherits `T` and everything works like a charm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another approach to writing expression templates that allows the arguments to be passed by value:

```
template <typename T>
struct Expr : T {
  Expr(T value) : T(value) { }
};

template <typename A,typename B>
struct Add {
  A a;
  B b;

  Add(A a,B b) : a(a), b(b) { }
};

template <typename A,typename B>
Expr<Add<A,B> > operator+(Expr<A> a,Expr<B> b)
{
  return Expr<Add<A,B> >(Add<A,B>(a,b));
}
```

There are a lot of implied copies, but I've found that the compiler does an excellent job of removing them.

To also make it convenient to use constants, you can write additional overloads:

```
template <typename A,typename B>
Expr<Add<Constant<A>,B> > operator+(const A& a,Expr<B> b)
{
  return Expr<Add<Constant<A>,B> >(Add<Constant<A>,B>(a,b));
}

template <typename A,typename B>
Expr<Add<A,Constant<B> > > operator+(Expr<A> a,const B& b)
{
  return Expr<Add<A,Constant<B> > >(Add<A,Constant<B> >(a,b));
}
```

where `Constant` is a class template, such as:

```
template <typename T>
struct Constant {
  const T& value;
  Constant(const T& value) : value(value) { }
};
```

There are a lot of implied copies, but I've found that the compiler does an excellent job of removing them.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is very good. Moreover this is move-semantics friendly (ie. there is no need for `Expr` to even be copyable, provided you `std::move` everywhere -- this will copy or move exactly in the right place) ! Let me test this on something more complex, to see if it scales.

Comment: Regarding your last edit: I don't understand what single-arg constructor for `T` would be called in `Expr`. I only see an `Add` constructor taking to arguments

Comment: @honk: Should call the automatically generated copy constructor.

Comment: I'd rather use a variadic perfect forwarding constructor in `Expr` (also I prefer a member than inheritance here, but this is a detail). This renders the implementation very concise. Thanks again.

Comment: I think `Add(a,b)` should be changed to `Add<Expr<A>, Expr<B>>(a,b)` for the code to compile.

Comment: How would this work for a concrete type like `matrix`? Would you have to make a factory function that wraps up `matrix` into an `Expr` in order to be compatible with `operator+`?

Comment: @void-pointer: I've extended the answer to address how to handle constants (non-expressions).

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks for the update. So there's a tradeoff between making the factory functions wrap `Constant` in an `Expr` or creating two additional overloads for each operator.

Answer (score 2):

Since the objects are cheap to move accoring to the comments, I would make the `operator+` take arguments by valueand letting the compiler work out how much copying it can avoid at the callsite. To avoid slicing that means that the `operator+` needs to work on the derived types (leading to a somewhat overeagerly binding `operator+`). To get that under control you'd probably need to use `std::enable_if` giving you something like the following:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Expr {
    typedef T expr_type;//added for getting T in the enable_if. Could probably also behandled with a custom type trait
};

template <typename L, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Expr<typename L::expr_type, L>, L>::value &&
                        std::is_base_of<Expr<typename L::expr_type, R>, R>::value, 
                        Add<typename L::expr_type, L, R>>::type
operator+(L l, R r) {
    return Add<typename L::expr_type, L, R>(std::move(l), std::move(r));
}
```

Of course for when using it more often, capsualating the condition in a trait is a good idea, giving you something like this:

```
template <typename L, typename R, typename T>
struct AreCompatibleExpressions {
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_base_of<Expr<T, L>, L>::value &&
                                  std::is_base_of<Expr<T, R>, R>::value;
};

template <typename L, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<AreCompatibleExpressions<L, R, typename L::expr_type>::value,
                        Add<typename L::expr_type, L, R>>::type
operator+(L l, R r) {
    return Add<typename L::expr_type, L, R>(std::move(l), std::move(r));
}
```

For even more brevity you could write your own `EnableIfCompatibleExpressions`, but that seems a bit overkill imo.

As a side note: You have a bug in the constructor for `Add`. It should be

```
Add(L left, R right) : l(std::move(left)), r(std::move(right))
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question, but this will warrant a macro to avoid typos. I'm not sure whether I prefer my four overloads or the `enable_if` expression.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Why would that warrant a macro? Of course you might want to wrap the whole condition into a new typetrait when you are writing it more often, but that isn't that complicated to do...

Comment: there is `operator+`, but also `operator-`, `*`, `/`, and other overloads that will involve as many `std::enable_if` expressions. Such complex expressions (either yours or mine) will need to be encapsulated into macros to avoid manual copy/pasting like hell (and this is *not* being paranoid: small typos here can be very hard to detect and to debug)

Comment: @AlexandreC.: As I said you might want to capsulate that in a type trait or even a custom `enable_if`. Modified my answer accordingly. Still no reason to resort to macros (those have their own way of being hard to debug afterall).

Comment: For the binary operations, the actual operation is handled via a template template parameter to a `Binary` template, so the `EnableIfCompatible` trait would be a good idea actually. Thanks for the typo in the question, I corrected it.